# AngularJS : difference between $rootScope.Controller and Service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to understand Angularjs behaviors.
I am building a web-app, and I want the CurrentUser's info be shared among all the app components. To do that, I have created a `CurrentUserController` bound to $rootScope. This controller is used by a `user` directive utilized in the `body` html element, so that it is globally accessible and it's created just one time.

```
app.controller('CurrentUserController', function ($rootScope) 
  {
   // initialization
   $rootScope.userCtrl = self; //<- MAKE IT GLOBAL
   this.islogged=false;
   this.name="";
   var self = this;
   // functions
   this.isLogged = function() 
        { return self.islogged; };

   this.setLoggedIn = function(credentials) 
        { self.islogged = true; }; 

   this.setLoggedOut = function() 
        { self.islogged = false; };                 
  }
);

app.directive('currentUser', function() {
  return {
    controller:'CurrentUserController'
  };
 })
```

and then my html page

```
<html>
...
<body current-user> 
...
</body>
</html>
```

However I read that `Services` should be used to share data between controllers, since they are *singleton*. 
So my question is:
**is my approach wrong, or it is equivalent as I utilized services?**

Moreover, right now I can utilize the directive `ng-switch` calling `$rootScope.userCtrl` functions, like this:

```
<div id="nav-right-side" class="navbar-right" ng-switch on="userCtrl.isLogged()">
            <div ng-switch-when="false">
                <login-button></login-button>
            </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
                <loggedin-button></loggedin-button>
            </div>                      

        </div>
```

If I utilize services, would I still be able to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The `$rootScope` is indeed shared across all the app and it is also best to store models into services.

Why bother with services ?
Because of the `$digest` cycle. Each time a watched value is modified, the digest is triggered. In angular, by default the digest is a loop that goes down all your scope from the `$rootScope` down to its leafs. On each element, it has to get if the value has been modified or not to update the view accordingly. This is pretty expensive, and it is the cause of why angular can be slow on big applications. Keeping the scope as light as possible is how you can build complex apps in angular. That's why storing things is always better in services, you do not pollute the scope with data you could put somewhere else.

That being said, auth is peculiar because you want to access the same data from the view and services. You can store it in the `$rootScope` as Asta puts it but I do not think that is consistant with best practices. **This is opinionated**

What can be done is creating a service that will hold you model and share it through a controller to have access to it from both the view and the other services/models.

**Session.js**

```
function Session(){
     var 
       self = this,

       _islogged=false,
       _name = '';
    // functions
    this.isLogged = function() { 
        return self.islogged; 
    };

    this.setLoggedIn = function() { 
         self.islogged = true; 
    }; 

    this.setLoggedOut = function() { 
        self.islogged = false; };                 
    }

    // GetUsername, setUsername ... Whatever you need
}
angular
    .module('app')
    .service('Session', Session);
```

**rootController.js**

```
function rootController(Session){
    // share the Session Service with the $scope
    // this.session is like $scope.session when using the controllerAS syntax.
    this.session = Session;
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('rootController', rootController);
```

I would suggest you take a look at these articles:

- [Techniques for Authentification in AngularJs Applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec)
- [Comprehensive 10 000 words tutorial in angular](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angularjs-tutorial)
- [Diving into controllerAs syntax](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)

Comment: Even if all the controllers share the same service, in this way I have to create a new instance of `rootController` in every (let's say) `div` or `directive` that needs it. Am i right?

Comment: No, you should not have too unless the directive have an isolated scope. In angular all child scope inherit from their parent scope. When not using the `controllerAs` syntax you would have to use `$scope.parent` to access the parent scope. With controller as, provided the different view are siblings you can access the session object from the view with `rootController.session`. You do not have to instantiate this multiple time. Putting it at the root of your app should be enough

Comment: So, as best practice, I should still use the controller in the `body` element, as my approach, but I should just externalize the behavior in a service

Comment: If you do it this way you will be using the login controller for all views and it simply initializes the session. I think you would be better to call a service directly and so avoid the extra controller layer.

Comment: @Delac Yes that is the way to go.

Comment: @Asta - the controller layer is only here to provide access to the user from the view. You might you to display some things according to the user groups, rights .... it is very useful to access it directly from template. I don' think you can achieve this without the controller

Comment: @Asta - for instance, I wouldn't know how to solve the `ng-switch` issue calling a service directly .....  so yes, even if it looks a bit weird to me too, it seems it should be used as @Nicolas said

Comment: I updated my answer for the global access part. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @NicolasJoseph you can access the `$rootScope` from any view so you should be able to just use a service. The additional part is ensuring the service is actually run when the app bootstraps.

Comment: @Asta - you can use the `$rootScope` but I am not sure that's very clean. To my mind your solution is equivalent to the one DeLac asked about. As far as maintainability is concerned you want to check `Session.isLoggedIn` not `$rootScope.sessionData.loggedIn` or `sessionData.loggedIn` things should be consistant and explicit. But I guess this is opinionated :)

Comment: You should still be able to keep things consistent and `$rootScope` is ideal for maintaining an app state. Either approach would be quite suitable I think with pro's and con's for either. I think your `rootController` approach would help avoid large run methods but has the consequence of the additional controller layer you may not want.

Answer (score 0):

Your best to use a `Service` to share data as you mention. In your approach you've used a `Controller` in a way that its not really intended.

You can call your controller from your `HTML` by using `ng-controller` so something like the following should work. This would be useful for a Login view for example or a logout directive.

```
<div ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <div id="nav-right-side" class="navbar-right" ng-switch on="isLogged()">
       <div ng-switch-when="false">
           <login-button></login-button>
       </div>
       <div ng-switch-when="true">
           <loggedin-button></loggedin-button>
       </div>                      
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to have your session available globally for use elsewhere you can use a `service` which you can initialise from your `app`. The session data can be added to `$rootScope` which you can then reference from any view or controller.

**Service**

```
angular.module('app').service('session', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.sessionData.loggedIn = true
    // extra logic etc..
});
```

**Main App**

```
angular.run(session)
angular.module('app').run(function(session) {});
```

Then to reference the variable from your view

```
<div id="nav-right-side" class="navbar-right" ng-switch on="sessionData.isLoggedIn">
```

Note: its good practice to use an object with `scope` variables to help avoid issues with inheritance.

Comment: but in this way `userCtrl` is accessible just in that div.... I'd like to use it from whatever I am

Comment: Ah yeah OK. I was imagining this controller on a particular view as this is what controllers are intended for. In your case the User logic can be inside a `service` and to instantiate it you can call it from your main `app.run` function. So instead of `isLogged()` you would set a `$rootScope` var indicating if they are logged in.

Comment: Updated my answer for use outside the directive

Comment: Then, to use a service in a controller, should I I use `$rootScope.sessionData`,  or I should inject the service as `.controller('controller', [function(session) {...}])`   ?

Comment: If you want to call any of the functions in the  `service` then you would inject the service in to the controller. If you just want to get the sessionData from `$rootScope` then you can just reference that directly. If you have an action that causes a user to become logged out for example (say, from an external action outwith the login/logout controller) then you can update `$rootScope` from that service or you could use events.